# delete div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to delete the `div` on button click but the problem that I need the button to delete the div that it contain to without passing the id of the div to the delete button

so this code at the end should be able to delete the div without passing the id of the div instead it will depend on passing `this` reference

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('mouseenter', '#divbutton', function() {
                $(this).find(":button").show();
            }).on('mouseleave', '#divbutton', function() {
                $(this).find(":button").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #divbutton {
            height: 100px;
            background: #0000ff;
        }

        #divbutton2 {
            height: 100px;
            background: #0000ff;
        }

        #divbutton3 {
            height: 100px;
            background: #0000ff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divbutton">
        <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="i" onclick="document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('divbutton'))">Hello</button>
    </div>

    <div id="divbutton2">
        <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="i" onclick="document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('divbutton2'))">Hello </button>
    </div>

    <div id="divbutton3">
        <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="i" onclick="document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('divbutton3'))">Hello </button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Format your javascript properly please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know how to use `this` reference to get hold of the parent element to pass it to `removeChild`, then it's quite easy, just use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode):

```
<div class="divbutton">
    <button type="button" style="display: none;" id="i" onclick="document.body.removeChild(this.parentNode)">Hello</button>
</div>
```

However, since you are using jQuery it makes sense to make use of it's power:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.divbutton', function () {
    $(this).find(":button").show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.divbutton', function () {
    $(this).find(":button").hide();
}).on('click', ':button', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I also changed ids `#divbuttonX` to class name `.divbutton`, CSS becomes simpler in this case too.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5qfjo0c7/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to remove the div

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('mouseenter', 'div[id^=divbutton]', function () {
                $(this).find(":button").show();
            }).on('mouseleave', 'div[id^=divbutton]', function () {
                $(this).find(":button").hide();
            });
           $(document).on('click', 'button#i', function () {
                $(this).closest("div").remove();
            });

 });
```

```css
#divbutton {
height: 100px;
background: #0000ff;
}

#divbutton2 {
height: 100px;
background: #0000ff;
}

#divbutton3 {
height: 100px;
 background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divbutton">
<button type="button" style="display: none;" id="i"  >Hello</button>
</div>

<div id="divbutton2" >
<button type="button" style="display: none;" id="i">Hello    </button>
</div>

<div id="divbutton3" >
<button type="button" style="display: none;" id="i">Hello    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it would help:

**$(this).parent().closest('div').hide();**

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().closest('div').hide();
});
```

**DEMO :**

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().closest('div').hide();
});
```

```css
#divbutton {
    background:powderblue;
    padding:10px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divbutton">
<button id="i">Hello</button>
</div>
```